# error de instalación con brew Mac

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

intento instalar php 8.2 pero me da el siguiente error
Failure while executing; `/usr/bin/env tar --extract --no-same-owner --file /Users/franciscoandriano/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/592c007136b235b78c9fa8eafda449719cdea58e2a4afe18b9a445cd0050ba1b--doxygen-1.9.7.src.tar.gz --directory /private/tmp/d20230527-41711-13grq6n` exited with 1. Here's the output:

alguien que me pueda ayudar a solucionarlo por favor

Comment: Parece que tienes que instalar | actualizar  doxygen